# Update is not updating but success message appears

Tags: php, laravel

I have a users table and I have a form to update the user profile:

When the "udpate" button is clicked it appears the success mesage but on the database is not updated, also on the form fields the changes dont appear.

Do you know why?

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('user.update')}}" class="clearfix">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{$user->name}}" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="surname">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" value="{{$user->surname}}" name="surname" class="form-control" id="surname" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Update controller edit and update methods:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('users.index')->with('user', Auth::user());
    }

    public function update(Request $request){

        dd($request->all());

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->surname = $request->surname;
        ...
        $user->save;
        Session::flash('success', 'Updated with success.');

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

routes:

```
Route::get('/user/profile', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@index',
    'as'   =>'user.index'
]);
Route::post('/user/profile/update', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@update',
    'as'   =>'user.update'
]);
```

Comment: I am kinda surprised that this TYPO does not cause an error to be generated somewhere

Comment: Suggest close as a TYPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with

```
 $user->save();
```

It is a function.

Comment: Also doesn't `dd($request->all());` kill the script?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$user->save();
```

and you can use on if

```
if($user->save()){
    // success message
} else {
    // error message
}
```